# Creating a field in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, field

I am new to using Core data.  I want to save the picture that the user took in the app and let the user choose a category for example vegetables, meat,etc.  I was reading a book and came to a sentence that says"create a field in the Core data entity that will denote the category" I don not get "create a field in the Core data" Does this mean attributes or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field in database terminology is equal to attribute.